# How to run node VueJS modules through Vueify using Gulp

Tags: gulp, vue.js, browserify, vuejs2, vue-component

I'm using Gulp, Browserify, and Vueify. I can create custom components just fine. They work great. But if I try to import/require a Vue component that was installed through node, things break.

For example, if I install the simple [Vue Numeric module](https://github.com/kevinongko/vue-numeric) with `npm install vue-numeric --save`, then require that module in my vue file and try to use it as a component, I get the following error message when I run my gulp compilation task (`gulp vue`):

```
G:\file...path\node_modules\vue-numeric\src\vue-numeric.vue:1
<template>
^
ParseError: Unexpected token
```

So basically it seems like Vueify is not being run on the `node_module` Vue files.

### My setup:

**gulpfile.js**

```
var gulp = require('gulp');
var fs = require("fs");
var browserify = require('browserify');
var vueify = require('vueify');
var babelify = require('babelify');
var gutil = require('gulp-util');

gulp.task('vue', function() {
    browserify('./assets/vue/vue.js')
      .transform(vueify)
      .transform(babelify)
      .bundle()
      .on('error', gutil.log)
      .pipe(fs.createWriteStream("../public/js/vue.js"));
});
```

**main.js** (my main Vue file)

```
var Vue = require('vue/dist/vue.common');

// This works perfectly with Vueify
var MyComponent = require('./components/myComponent.vue');

// Vueify doesn't seem to process this component
var VueNumeric = require('vue-numeric');

var app = new Vue({
    el: '#app',
    components: {
        MyComponent,
        VueNumeric
    }
})
```

**myComponent.vue** (Just to show you that Vueify is working on my components)

```
<style>
  .red {
    color: #f00;
  }
</style>

<template>
  <h1 class="red">{{msg}}</h1>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  data () {
    return {
      msg: 'Hello world!'
    }
  }
}
</script>
```

Any ideas?